# Unable to install the printer driver . Operation could not be completed (error 0x0000007e)

Tags: installation, driver, connect, network-printers

When I try to install printer driver on Win7 (x86,x64),2008R2 ,Windows 8.1 and 2012R2 I get error "Unable to install the printer driver. Operation could not be completed (error 0x0000007e) . And when I try installing PNP driver , It says "cannot connect printer ". Please let me know how to resolve this issue .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error will appear when the driver package is updated with Visual studio 2017 . Microsoft has fixed this issue on their latest KB updates . Please update your OSes to latest windows updates . For windows 7/2008R2 you can install following  KB to resolve this issue . https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4467107 . For Win8.1/2012R2 please update the OS to latest windows updates .